# MySQL: Get Multiple Rows With The Same Data to go Across Columns

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to make a table that lists all the different employers and staff assignments that go along with that employer for each client. But they way they populate out of our database is by duplicate rows per client, so it looks like this:

```
id  name    staff            employer
1   Joe     Seinfeld, Jerry  Body Shop
1   Joe     Seinfeld, Jerry  Party Inc.
2   Puddy   Seinfeld, Jerry  Body Shop
3   Newman  Costanza, George Computers Inc.
3   Newman  Benes, Elaine    Postal Service
4   Delores Seinfeld, Jerry  Mulva LLC
5   Morty   Kramer, Cosmo    Executive Raincoats
```

As you can see by the multiple IDs in column 1, Joe works for two places (Body Shop and Party Inc.), so two rows populate for him. Whereas I'd like to run a MySQL query and get Joe (and any other multiple job people) on one row listing everything out. Something like:

```
id  name    staff1           employer1           staff2          employer2
1   Joe     Seinfeld, Jerry  Body Shop           Seinfeld, Jerry Party Inc.
2   Puddy   Seinfeld, Jerry  Body Shop      
3   Newman  Costanza, George Computers Inc.      Benes, Elaine   Postal Service
4   Delores Seinfeld, Jerry  Mulva LLC      
5   Morty   Kramer, Cosmo    Executive Raincoats
```

Or whatever way would be the easiest to show all the data but removing all duplicate IDs and displaying them in additional columns attached to that ID instead. Also, each employer is assigned to a staff member -- and no two staff members will have the same employer (even though the database doesn't export it as a separate table).

Hope that makes sense! I also made a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0118a9/6) that has a few more examples (along with another table that matches up staff name with their email, which is another [less important] part of the query).

Comment: Can there be more than 2 employers?  If not, you can `pivot` the results using conditional aggregation.  If you don't know the max number, you'll need to use `dynamic sql`.

Comment: @sgeddes       There are *very* few who have three employers, and that's the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` window function with a `PARTITION BY` clause, not available in MySQL:

```
SELECT ID, name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN employer END) AS employer1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN staff END) AS staff1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN employer END) AS employer2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN staff END) AS staff2
FROM (     
  SELECT ID, name, employer, staff, email,
         @rn := IF(@id = t1.ID, @rn + 1,
                  IF(@id := t1.ID, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.name, t1.employer, t1.staff, t2.email
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.staff = t2.staff) AS t1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @id := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY ID) AS t2
GROUP BY ID, name
```

Variable `@rn` enumerates records within each `ID` partition. Using `@rn` we can apply *conditional aggregation* so as to pivot fields `employer`, `staff`, `email`, etc. of the original table.

**Note:** The above query handles a maximum number of `2` records for each `ID`. It can be easily extended to accommodate a larger population of `ID` partitions.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0118a9/12)

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment that 3 is the max, you can use `conditional aggregation` to `pivot` your results.  You'll also need to define a `row_number` per group.

Here's an example:

```
select id, name, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then staff end) as staff1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then employer end) as employer1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then staff end) as staff2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then employer end) as employer2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then staff end) as staff3,
    max(case when rn = 3 then employer end) as employer3
from (
    select *, @rn:=if(@previd=id,@rn+1,1) rn, @previd:=id
    from yourtable, (select @rn:=1, @previd:=0) t
    order by id
    ) t
group by id, name
```